# How do I prevent browser caching of webpack bundle?

Tags: reactjs, caching, webpack

I am using webpack to bundle a react app in a js file which I want add to client site. So I end up with a `app.js` and I can provide a url for where the file is hosted to clients `https://example.mysite.com/apps/app.js` and this can be included via a script tag on client site. Simple enough.

The issue I might run into here is browser side caching. I can't use version tags here because asking a client to continuously update code on their site is not a realistic expectation.

Webpack hashing is also not an option because this would mean updating the file on the client side, which again is something I would like to work around.

Is there a way to prevent my `app.js` file from being cached and fetching a new version of the file every time the `app.js` file has changed?

Comment: Webpack allows you to add content hashes to file names for exactly this purpose https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/

Comment: @PatrickHund the js resource will be implemented on a site I will not have access to. So, content hashes aren't an options as this would required continuously updating the file name on the site.

Comment: If you create the script tag with some templating system, you can always add a bogus URL parameter with a time stamp to the script tag for cache busting. That will, however, make the browser load the bundle with every request, which is suboptimal for site speed

Comment: @PatrickHund yeah, I would just set request headers not to cache if I wanted to just pull the entire bundle every time..which I might end up having to do if I can't find a solution.

Comment: You can add a timestamp to the url  'app.js?cache='+ new Date().getTime()